# **kwargs opcional com default

Tags: python, python-3.x

É comum encontrar várias apis que fazem uso do `KeyWordArgument` do python. Minha dúvida é como usar esse recuso para atributos de objetos.
As vezes quando uso uma API e passo um parâmetro nomeado `param=True` e a classe que estou instanciando não tem um atributo com esse nome, recebo uma exceção informando que a classe não tem uma propriedade com esse nome, exemplo:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> a = Gtk.Button(label='Um botao')
>>> z = Gtk.Button(labelll='Um botao')
TypeError: gobject GtkButton doesn't support property 'labelll'
```

Pergunta, como implemento isso nas minhas classes? Outra funcionalidade também é que o usuário pode escolher quais parâmetros quer passar, e aqueles que ele não informar tem valores default.

A maneira que achei para conseguir isso é definindo valores padrão como em: `def __init__(self, paran1=True, paran2=False, paran3='anything')` Mas como conseguir o mesmo efeito usando: `def __init__(self, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: Raciocinado um pouco acho que `**kwargs` não faz sentido se você tem uma quantidade específica de parâmetros, como é o caso dos atributos de uma classe.
Acho que `**kwargs` só faz sentido se você tem uma função que possa receber qualquer quantidade de parâmetros como: `def soma_os_parametros(**kwargs):`.
Mas `**kwargs` é útil quando você tem uma boa quantidade de parâmetros .
Imaginemos um objeto com 10 atributos onde todos podem ser passados via `__init__` e todos tendo valor padrão. `**kwargs` pouparia digitação.

Comment: Eu encontrei essa [solução](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1098605/5913854). Mas como é uma pergunta antiga quem sabe exista uma solução mais elegante atualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Outra funcionalidade também é que o usuário pode escolher quais parâmetros quer passar, e aqueles que ele não informar tem valores *default*.

Assumindo que [`kwargs`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) é um dicionário, você pode usar o método [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) para obter um valor, e se preferir, definir um valor padrão, caso não indique um e a chave não exista, uma exceção [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) é lançada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.nome = kwargs.get('nome', 'Joao')
        self.peso = kwargs.get('peso', 80)
        self.idade = kwargs.get('idade', 60)

    def foo(self):
        print (self.nome, self.peso, self.idade)

pessoa = Pessoa(peso = 70, idade = 50)  # nome não foi indicado, Joao vai ser o padrão
pessoa.foo()  # Joao 70 50
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](https://repl.it/EBFG/0)</kbd>

Comment: Se quiser usar um dicionário ao invés de variáveis, dá para fazer [**assim**](https://repl.it/EBFG/1).